# Opencv c++ drawing on image

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to draw a circle on image after a mouse click.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

using namespace cv;


static Mat img_object;

static void onMouse(int event, int x, int y, int, void*){
    Point pt1 = Point(x, y);
    circle(img_object, pt1, 1, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 100, 8, 0);
    imshow("Display window", img_object);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    img_object = imread("pic.jpg");

    setMouseCallback("Display window", onMouse, 0);

    imshow("Display window", img_object);

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run it the image is shown but nothing happens when I click on the image.

Comment: Is `circle(img_object, pt1, 1, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 100, 8, 0);` doing what it should? You want a fully filled green circle which has a radius of 100? Try `circle(img_object, pt1, 100, Scalar(0, 255, 0), -1, 8, 0);`.

Comment: after the last change @berak suggested it did draw the circle but every time the mouse pointer was on it without mouse click.

Comment: This might have other reasons. The only thing I see, is that for drawing a filled circle of 100 pixel radius it is normally the radius specified as 100 and the thickness of -1. In your circle call you draw a circle of 1 pixel radius with a 100 thickness, what should logically be also 100 pixel radius filled circle as long as the thickness expands half inside and half outside the radius...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're  redeclaring a local Mat:

```
static Mat img_object = imread("pic.jpg");
```

inside main, thus shadowing the global one.

replace that line with:

```
img_object = imread("pic.jpg");
```

and everything will be fine.

## ----

better even, skip the global object, and pass the mat to the callback function:

```
using namespace cv;

static void onMouse(int event, int x, int y, int, void* imgptr){
    if ( event != 1 ) return;     // only draw on lmouse down
    Mat & img = (*(Mat*)imgptr)); // first cast, then deref
    Point pt1 = Point(x, y);
    circle(img, pt1, 1, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 100, 8, 0);
    imshow("Display window", img);
    waitKey(1);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    namedWindow("Display window",0);
    Mat img = imread("pic.jpg");
    setMouseCallback("Display window", onMouse, &img); // pass ptr to mat here
    imshow("Display window", img);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried the code that you wrote and it still doesn't draw a circle on the image

Comment: ah sorry still calling img_show, also missing a waitKey(1); please look at the edit

Comment: I'm not sure if the mouse click invokes onMouse function. I put a breakpoint there and i didn't stop there.

Comment: sorry, my bad, being sloppy here: it needed an additional namedWindow call, see edit, again.

Comment: now it does draw a circle but without a click. If the mouse pointer is on the image it just draws a circle. is there a way to make it draw only after a click?

Comment: found the solution. 
THANK YOU!!